# Xcode - Control reaches end of non-void function operator error

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Hello guys im using Xcode on Yosemite OS, when i try to use these operators i got error Control reaches end of non-void function,could someone tell me how to fix it?

```
`A& A::operator= (A& src)`
{

    delete[] b_;

    i_ = src.i_;
    b_ = new B[i_];
    for(int i = 0; i < i_; i++)
        b_[i].set(src.b_[i].get());

} `//Here appear this error>> Control reaches end of non-void function`


    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& str, const A& a)
 {
     str << a.i_ << ":";
        for(int i = 0; i < a.i_; ++i)
            str << " " << a.b_[i].get();``
        return str << std::endl;

}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& str, A &a)
{
    int i;
    str >> i;

    A* b = new A(i);
    a = *b;

} //Here appear this error>> Control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: You should return `*this` and `str` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from functions that are declared to return a value.  For example:

```
A& A::operator= (A& src)`
{

    delete[] b_;

    i_ = src.i_;
    b_ = new B[i_];
    for(int i = 0; i < i_; i++)
        b_[i].set(src.b_[i].get());

  return *this;  // <-- return something
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& str, A &a)
{
    int i;
    str >> i;

    A* b = new A(i);
    a = *b;

  return str;  // <-- return something
}
```

The specific error you are getting - "Control reaches end of non-void function" simply means that the compiler encounters the end of the function body without a statement that returns a value for a function whose signature indicates that it is supposed return something (the "non-void" part of the error message).